# Ranking function approximation

Tags: optimization

I have a matrix function, which roughly looks like this:
$$
Y_{i,j,k} = f(coef, A, B) = coef[i] * A_{i,j} * B_{i,k}
$$

```
def fn(coef, A, B):
    return np.einsum("i,ij,ik->ijk", coef, A, B)
```

Given, say, following values for *coef*, *A*, *B*:

```
coef = [1, 4, 16]
A = [
    [.11, .12],
    [.91, .52],
    [.31, .32]
]
B = [
    [.11, .12, .13],
    [.91, .72, .63],
    [.31, .52, .73]
]
```

3d matrix produced by function *fn* can be visualized like this (I'm just stacking together two slices horizontally, to make it possible to visualize a matrix in 2d):

```
heatmap(
    np.hstack((
        y[:,0,:],
        y[:,1,:]
    ))
)
```

[image]

Given a target (constant) 3d matrix, I need to find values for input parameters *A* and *B* such, that they restore element ranks along axis=0.

[image]

I was trying to solve this problem minimizing following objective function, using SLSQP implementation provided by scipy.optimize package:

$C=\sum_{j,k} |R_{jk}-\hat R_{jk}|$, where:

$R$ - given target constant matrix ranks
$\hat R$ - actual matrix ranks
$R = argsort(Y) $

```
def objective_fn(coef, A, B, expected_matrix):
    expected_ranks = expected_matrix.argsort(axis=0)
    actual_ranks = np.einsum("i,ij,ik->ijk", coef, A, B)
    diff = abs(expected_ranks - actual_ranks)
    return diff.sum()
```

It sort of works.

[image]

However, results don't always match expectations. It seems to me, that since objective *ranking* function is not differentiable, classic optimization using SLSQP may not be an optimal approach here.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any better ways to solve a problem like this?
2. Is it possible to use matrix decomposition/factorization here so
   that result factor matrices have specified dimensionality?

Comment: Can you make your question accessible to people not familiar with numpy?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus hope it helps. Although not sure what's the right notation for argsort would be.

Comment: I still see a lot of code. Can you make your question more concise, and do away with code entirely? As for notation, you can use whatever notation you want, as long as you *explain* it. I have no idea what *argsort* is supposed to represent.